# OnClick() with Highcharts in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

I'm a coop student and I'm working with Highcharts in MVC 4. My employer would like to be able to click on a column on a Column chart and have it take the user to a new page. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

I'm having a hard time finding examples of Highcharts in MVC, so if someone has some good resources please send them my way.

Comment: Defaulty in the highcharts you should catch [click event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click) on serie's point. Check that [wrappers for asp.net](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/14-articles/2-third-party-implementation/) supports that option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sebastian! Using your first resource I was able to figure it out.

Comment: I posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment and the resource [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click) I was able to solve my own problem. My view takes in a Highcharts object as the model, and when my Controller passes it the following Highcharts object it works:

```
new Highcharts("chart")
//define the type of chart 
.InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column})
//overall Title of the chart 
.SetTitle(new Title { Text = chartTitle })
//small label below the main Title
.SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = subTitle })
//load the X values
.SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = xAxisData })
//set the Y title
.SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = yAxisTitle } })
.SetTooltip(new Tooltip
{
    Enabled = true,
    Formatter = @"function() { return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ this.x +': '+ this.y; }"
})
.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
{
    Line = new PlotOptionsLine
    {
        DataLabels = new PlotOptionsLineDataLabels
        {
            // this makes the value of the dot appear above it if it is set to true (for Line charts)
            Enabled = true
        },
        // set to true so that when the user hovers their mouse over a column/dot it's value and name will appear
        EnableMouseTracking = true
    },
    /***********
     * IMPORTANT PART
     ************/
    Series = new PlotOptionsSeries
    {
        Point = new PlotOptionsSeriesPoint
        {
            Events = new PlotOptionsSeriesPointEvents
            {
                // Here you can put code for different event handlers (like Click and MouseOver) in javaScript.
                // The one below makes an alert box pop up with the name of the column and its value when a 
                // column is clicked
                Click = "function () {alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);}"                   
            }
        }
    }
})
//load the Y values 
.SetSeries(yAxisData.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Defaulty in the highcharts you should catch [click event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click) on serie's point.

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Check that [wrappers](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/14-articles/2-third-party-implementation/) for asp.net supports that option.